# Calculating average time of events with same ID

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I'm trying to calculate the average of the elapsed time of events with the same id.

`Event 1` started at `123` and ended at `129` -> it lasted `6` seconds.
`Event 2` started at `134` and ended at `138` -> it lasted `4` seconds.

| time | id |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 1 |
| 125 | 1 |
| 129 | 1 |
| 134 | 2 |
| 138 | 2 |

The average would be `5` seconds.

---

Like this I just get all elapsed times, not grouped by ids.

```
SELECT elapsed(id)
FROM measurement1
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the query for getting all the elapsed times as a subquery to get the average time elapsed across id's.

```
SELECT AVG(elapsed)
FROM (
  SELECT MAX(time) - MIN(time) as elapsed
  FROM measurement1
  GROUP BY id1
)
```

Comment: When I just do `SELECT MAX(time) from measurement1` I get `No data`. But there is enough data available.

Comment: Then there is an unrelated problem, as your query should return 138 from the posted dataset. I also see that your dataset has no primary key.